# How to put if one range is bigger than other in Countifs function in google sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I need a formula for number of wins of particular player in league.
So I need to count all the wins of one player, and to do that, I need to put range of goals scored and that range has to be bigger than goals concieved in order to be counted as win.

I tried with this formula but it's not working:

```
=Countifs(K7:K19,"Nikolinho Pueblo Jr.",L7:M19, L7:L19>M7:M19 )
```

[image: Table picture]

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**:  Added IFERROR formula to the end and expanded for 2 ends based on comments.

You can count the returned items from a Query:

```
=COUNTA( QUERY( K7:M19,"select K where K = 'Nikolinho Pueblo Jr.' and L > M", 0))
```

With this, you can substitute cell references for the values if needed, and also open the range to go to the last line:

```
=COUNTA( QUERY( K7:M,"select K where K = '" & B2 & "' and L > M", 0))
```

This will give the count for the name in cell B2.

In order to not count an query which returns no results (it returns an error), use the following:

```
=COUNTA( IFERROR( QUERY( L7:N,"select N where N = '" & J1 & "' and M > L", 0),), IFERROR( QUERY( K7:M,"select K where K = '" & J1 & "' and L > M", 0),))
```

**ADDED**:
To check for the winner from 2 columns, you can place 2 query formulas in the COUNTA such as:

```
=COUNTA( IFERROR( QUERY( L7:N,"select N where N = '" & A10 & "' and M > L", 0),), IFERROR( QUERY( K7:M,"select K where K = '" & A10 & "' and L > M", 0),))
```

You can also do this with one query:

```
=COUNTA( QUERY( K7:N,"select K where (K = '" & A10  & "' and L > M) or (N = '" & A10 & "' and M > L) ", 0))
```

Comment: awesome, it works, I just added one more line + counta(query(...) for when player is away.

Comment: sry to bother, it gives good results for first two players but for third ''El Patrino'' it gives result as 2 but he has only one win.
code is: =COUNTA( QUERY( K7:M,"select K where K = '" & A10 & "' and L > M", 0))+COUNTA( QUERY( L7:N,"select N where N = '" & A10 & "' and M > L", 0))

Comment: Can you add access to a sample file?  You appear to be looking at different/additional criteria now.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14MBrG1UF3-Z_sO6qdF4a60TWZpr9mQANgxe65upfo8E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See my edits above.  I had to add an IFERROR to skip counting a query which returned no results.

Answer (score 0):

You want to first total up the wins where the player appears in column `K` by comparing the scores to those on the right, then add up the wins on the right by comparing to the scores on the left where the player appears in column `N`.

**Updated Formula:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($K$7:$K$19="Nikolinho Pueblo Jr.")*($L$7:$L$19>$M$7:$M$19))+SUMPRODUCT(($N$7:$N$19="Nikolinho Pueblo Jr.")*($M$7:$M$19>$L$7:$L$19))
```

Comment: When I use it in second formula it gives me also 4 as result, but it should be 3?

=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(K7:K19,"Pietro Lombardo",L7:L19,">"&M7:M19)+COUNTIFS(N7:N19,"Pietro Lombardo",M7:M19,">"&L7:L19))

Comment: Sorry my bad, that doesn't work as I though at all! I've got a solution though. I'll update answer now.

Comment: It is for me... it's counting any wins where the player is on the left and the wins on the right. Draws aren't being counted and neither are losses..?

Comment: http://imgur.com/Wg5CdU4

And result should be 3, you can count it in the right results

Comment: The `>` (greater than sign) needs to be used in both `SUMPRODUCT` formulas, your second is using `<` (lesser than).